# What is the right way to do a DELETE in NextJS 13.4 API? (Response, NextAPIResponse, NextResponse) using the new App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13, supabase

What is the right way to do a simple DELETE in NextJS 13.4 in the new `App Router`?

The previous way of doing delete with using `NextAPIRequest, NextAPIResponse`, using `if (req.method === 'DELETE')` , pulling parameters from the URL via something like this `const { id } = request.query;`, and throwing error messages with `NextAPIResponse` seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated DELETE api in NextJS 13.4 using the new `app routing` with error messages included.

For clarity of the example, I'll include a call to a `supabase client`; the API you're calling can be different but you can see the error messages and such.

```
// FILE NAME /app/api/tacos/route.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import supabase from '../../supabase/client';

export async function DELETE(request) {

  // ! OLD WAY - no longer works
  // const { id } = request.query;

  // * THIS WORKS AND IS RECOMMENDED
  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams;
  const id = searchParams.get('id');

  //! NOTE: THIS DOES NOT WORK
  // const myAPIUrl = request.nextUrl.myAPIUrl;
  // const id = myAPIUrl.get('id');

  try {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('my_table').delete().eq('id', id);

    if (error) {
      return NextResponse({ error: 'Failed to delete item' }, { status: 500 });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ data });

  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse(
      { error: 'Internal server error - delete ' },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

For clarity, in Typescript this function signature would be
`export async function DELETE(request: NextRequest) {`

Read more on route handlers [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).

And for completeness, here is a very simple function I used in my client-side app to call this API.  For simplicity, I hardcoded an `id`; in your app, you would want to pass am `id` as a parameter to the deleteSupabaseItem function.

```
// This is being called from a Page in your React app
// 'use client';
// import React from 'react`;
// ... define your other import statements here

const deleteSupabaseItem = async () => {

  const id = '23423dfe-2343-2323223-232323-232323223';

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/tacos?id=${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log('deleteSupabaseItem - ResponseOK - data deleted', responseData);
    } else {
      // Handle the error
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log('deleteSupabaseItem - Response not OK', responseData);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const responseData = await response.json();
    console.log('deleteSupabaseItem - try/catch error', responseData);
    console.error('deleteSupabaseItem - try/catch error - error', error);
  }
};

// ... define the rest of your React Page here
```

Note: You can of course consolidate responseData declaration higher up in code, but I kept it simple, with a smaller scope for readability.